# AWS Email Workflow

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have been working on AWS for the last month trying to scale our application email sending, we were using email chimp and decided to migrate our servers to amazon. Our application currently generates between 3000-4000 emails a day (not all at once and in different time span). The issue i'm trying to solve is deliver the emails in the least time possible (SES send is 14 mails/s.)

What i been able to do is: Application -> SQS -> Lambda pull (schedule 1 per minute that pull 10 messages) -> SES -> SNS -> Application.

The Lambda schedule is generated with the cloudwatch rule, i've seen that you can target events but i haven't been able to do it =(

I'm trying to find the correct approach but i haven't been able to put all my thoughts together.

Can anyone help me? =)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly if you want to increase the maximum send rate, you may [open a case](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/submit-extended-access-request.html) in the Support Center.

Then you could setup a CloudWatch alarm for your SQS `NumberOfMessagesSent` metric and [call a SNS topic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQS_AlarmMetrics.html) that triggers a Lambda. You can trigger this Lambda if your `NumberOfMessagesSent` is greater than a certain value. eg: 1, 10 or maximum SES send rate. Lambda could call SES and send emails for the newly added messages. The method that I'm proposing is SNS -> Lambda -> SES. In this method, you may not want to rely on a schedule.

Comment: Thank you very much, i was really looking for some help. In your method SQS is before SNS? Or no SQS at all?

Comment: Assuming that you already have a SQS setup, it should come before SNS. CloudWatch alarm will trigger an SNS and SNS will trigger Lambda. I would recommend to have a SQS such that it decouples your application related functions and email sending.

Comment: Yes, i already have them decoupled! Thank you very much, i'm going to try this way. My main man manojf! :)